# Query based on datetime interval

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to find out which driver is available during a certain time based on his start and end datetime.

I have two worksheets.

Worksheet1 displayes the start and end time of drivers in datetime:

```
Driver   | Start Time       | End Time
------------------------------------------
Driver 1 | 25-05-2015 09:00 | 25-05-2015 15:00
Driver 2 | 25-05-2015 15:00 | 25-05-2015 21:00
Driver 2 | 26-05-2015 09:00 | 26-05-2015 15:00
Driver 1 | 26-05-2015 12:00 | 26-05-2015 17:00
```

Worksheet2 displays the start date of a tour

```
Tour 1 | 25-05-2015 11:00
Tour 2 | 25-05-2015 16:00
Tour 3 | 25-05-2015 17:00
Tour 4 | 26-05-2015 09:00
```

I would like to query in worksheet 2 which driver from worksheet 1 is available during the time of the tour start.

```
=QUERY(Worksheet1!A:C,"select A where C <= date '"&text(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'",0)
```

But I understand that I will need to be working with timedate instead (to get the actual times of the start and end of the shifts) and I will need to query an interval.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use dates and times, you need [`datetime`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals) instead of `date`. And since there is an interval, another comparison should be made with column B. The query string, shown with linebreaks for readability, would be

```
"select A 
   where B <= datetime '" & text(A2, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "' 
     and C >= datetime '" & text(A2, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'"
```

This ensures that the datetime in A2 is between the datetimes in columns B and C.